# Should a TypeScript Library's repo contain the JS version?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dependencies

Should the repository for a library written in Typescript contain a JS version for the consumer? Or should I leave it to the consumer to compile it themselves? Or neither?

Comment: I would call a person using the repo a potential contributor and, for them, there's no need for the repo to contain the JS - they'll be building it. A consumer - using an NPM-distributed package - should be using already compiled `.js` and `.d.ts` files. So, no for the repo, but yes for the NPM package. If the repo itself is the NPM package, use `.gitignore` and `.npmignore` files to control the publishing if the compiled files to NPM, whilst ignoring them for git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, I only include the source files in the repo. There is a reasonable expectation that a person downloading the source will want to work with the source and build it. Meanwhile you can offer build tools/commands to help them build it. For npm modules, your package.json might have a postinstall script that runs the `tsc` command. As long as TypeScript is a dependency, npm will download the necessary libraries and execute the TypeScript build when the user does an `npm install` on the repo once cloned locally.

Comment: Thanks. This gives me some direction.